# Sum of $2$ squares and factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that if $x$ and $y$ are coprime any odd factor of $x^2+y^2$ when divided by $4$ gives a remainder of $1$?
It is some way linked to every prime $p=4i+1$ is a sum of two squares which i saw here. 
Tx

Comment: $2\mid(3^2+5^2)$.

Comment: Try $13$ and $17$

Comment: realy sorry i meant odd factors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion is true with the exepction of even divisors (as noted int he comments).

Any number of the form $4m+3$ needs to have a prime factor of the form $4k+3$ (if not, it would be a product of primes all $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so it would itself be $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$).

So if $x^2+y^2$ had a divisor $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, it actually would have a prime divisor $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. That means

$$x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p.$$

$y \equiv 0 \pmod p$ would imply $x \equiv 0 \pmod p$, which is contrary to the assumption of $x,y$ being coprime. So we can write the above as

$$\left(\frac{x}y\right)^2\equiv -1 \pmod p,$$

where $\frac{x}y$ is taken in $\mathbb Z_p$.

If we take both sides to the $\frac{p-1}2$-th power, we get

$$\left(\frac{x}y\right)^{p-1}\equiv -1 \pmod p,$$

because $\frac{p-1}2$ is odd ($=2k+1$ if $p=4k+3$).

However, since the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_p$ contains $p-1$ elements, by Lagrange's law we have

$$z^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p, \forall z=1,2,\ldots,p-1$$.

Finally $\frac{x}y \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is also impossible, so we have a contradiction.